# Приложение зависает при использовании меню

Tags: qt5, qml, qtquick

Есть прямоугольник, который меняет цвет при наведении мыши. На прямоугольнике расположена кнопка с меню. После нескольких кликов на пункты меню, прямоугольник перестает менять цвет при наведении мыши.

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQml 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

Window {
    visible: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent

        color: "grey"

        MouseArea {
            id: area
            hoverEnabled: true
            anchors.fill: parent

            onEntered: {
                rect.color = "white"
            }

            onExited: {
                rect.color = "grey"
            }
        }

        Button {
            text: "Button1"
            menu: Menu {
                MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
                MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Странно, у меня всё окей

Comment: Вячеслав, спасибо за ответ! Возможно надо подольше пощелкать на меню, первый раз у меня тоже не сразу воспроизвелось.